# Structured Streaming job fails when there is no data in one kafka topic partition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

When I try to retrieve data from kafka topic by timestamps for offsets, job fails with an error:

> Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No offset matched from request of topic-partition topicA-0 and timestamp 1686877634000.

The problem is that there is actually data in the topic, but only in partition-1, but still job fails, because there is no data in partition-0.

Code that I use:

```
        df_stream = (
            spark.read.format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_servers)
            .option("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
            .option("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
            .option("subscribe", kafka_topic)
            .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT")
            .option("kafka.group.id", kafka_group_id)
            .option("startingOffsetsByTimestamp", """{"topicA":{"0": 1686877634000, "1": 1686877634000}}""")
            .option("endingOffsetsByTimestamp", """{"topicA":{"0": 1686881234000, "1": 1686881234000}""")
            .option("failOnDataLoss", false) 
            .options(**options)
            .load()
        )
```

Is there a way to avoid this error? I need to retrieve data for specific timestamps. I tried to read all data in the topic and filter by kafka timestamp and it works, but I don't think it's a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the starting offset of your partition 0 to another value.
if you look at your `checkpointing` directory (set during the sparksession creation), and inspect the `offsets` directory, you should be able to set value of your partition to start the stream.

Comment: I'm not trying to read in stream, I'm trying to read in batch, so there's no checkpoints.